# how to compile and install a driver module ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, kernel, 17.10

I have a problem with my ethernet card on my Lenovo Thinkpad t510 so I want to remove the one that came by default with the OS and download from intel to install it again.

The steps to install are given [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005480/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.htm), but I am new to ubuntu and do not know exactly what I am supposed to do on the step 4. My OS has the driver in with the driver inside `/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel`

`ip link` gives :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP
mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:3d:fd:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode
DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 58:94:6b:be:e5:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 4: enp0s29u1u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state
UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4e:01:d4:8f:8d:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: This sounds somewhat like a [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Intel NIC's are fairly well tested against Linux kernels. What problem do you expirience?

Comment: The wired connection is not working... I posted it here https://askubuntu.com/questions/975184/lan-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-10 but I have not gotten an answer and I need it badly so I post the installation problem separately here.

Comment: You said it is not working. How have you verified this? What is the output of e.g. `ip link`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lan is not working on ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975184/lan-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: I don't consider this question duplicate because the other question is about the driver not working but here it about compiling and installing a driver.

Comment: The card appears (`enp0s25`), so I think there's a very good chance you are wasting your time by trying the driver. As I said Intel cards are very well tested in mainstream kernel. It's *not* the place I'd start looking.

Comment: @vidarlo What do you think may be the problem then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68639/discussion-between-aidonsnous-and-vidarlo).